# PDO replacing mysqli

Tags: php, pdo

I'm convinced that I need to migrate to PDO and am working my way through.  I have two questions so far...

(1) Is is always appropriate to use a prepared statement?  What if I simply want to list a set or records from a table and there will only be one query on that table?  Doesn't a prepared statement slow things down for the first query?

(2) Let's say I have a table with 10 fields.  Can I declare a class that has only six of those fields and then use  PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "foo"  where "foo" is my abbreviated class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think it's good practice to prioritize prepared statement as much as possible. I've used PDO in a heavy traffic project (*) in my company and we've found that calls like `require_once` are way more problematic than PDO queries (in our architecture, at least).
2. Yes, but the other 4 fields will be available anyways. For example:

```
class Foo {
    private $col1;
    private $col2;

    public static function findAll()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO(...);
        $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo');
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Foo');
    }
}

print_r(Foo::findAll());
```

Let's assume that the table 'foo' has the columns col1, col2, col3 and col4, then the above code will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Foo Object
        (
            [col1:Foo:private] => 1
            [col2:Foo:private] => 2
            [col3] => 3
            [col4] => 4
        )
...
)
```

- Just to give you some perspective: it was a somewhat simple state-wide online election that was anounced in mass media vehicles and it lasted for about 40 hours. Our state has something above 8 million active electors but less than 1 million has voted.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is considered to be negligible. Really. Nobody ever reported a problem with performance caused by prepared statements (Though, there is too small a number of people who really use them, not just tell others to use them, but anyway).

*IF* this imaginary problem still bugs you too much, PDO has an emulation mode for you, when no real prepare used and only one roundtrip to database performed, as if no prepared statement is used at all. Equally safe.

So - yes, always use prepared statement. Just make a habit out of it.

I find this silly syntax sugar of `FETCH_CLASS` quite useless and never used it myself. Yet, if you are asking for a permission to be lazy and use `*` instead of listing all the six required fields manually - why not try it and see?

*A note on the tile:*
Although there are no technical reasons to replace *mysqli* (as this *improved* mysql library considered as good as PDO), yet, as you are most likely going to use raw API calls in the application code, PDO indeed is way better replacement for the old mysql ext

Comment: My understanding of PDO versus prepared statements in mysqli is that with PDO the parameters can be named; whereas in mysqli they cannot.  So it seems that going full-bore to PDO is by far the best overall approach.  thaks to all of you who took your time to respond.